# How to send a @mydomain email from Gmail, without paying

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I want to be able to **receive** email from a few **xxx@mydomain** email accounts and also **send** email from those addresses for free (or very, very cheap - 40$/year per user is too much).

To receive my email in Gmail, I thought of just using a free email forwarding service from a DNS registrar offer. Something like:

```
mail_1@mydomain.com  ->  forward to freemail_1@gmail.com
mail_2@mydomain.com  ->  forward to freemail_2@gmail.com
```

Easy. Now, how can I send emails from **mail_1@mydomain.com** (without any "behalf")?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I send emails from mail_1@mydomain.com (without any "behalf")?

Whether the "behalf" (or "sent via") is visible is dependent on the email client receiving the email, however, it can always be dug out by viewing the source of the email. You get the "behalf" when using Gmail's SMTP server (the default) to send the email. Gmail will add a `Sender:` header with the gmail address of the account actually sending the email. This is correct behaviour as far as I'm aware and helps prevent your email being blocked as spam.

To remove the "behalf" when sending from Gmail, you need to use an alternative SMTP server - preferably one that is associated with the account/domain through which you are sending mail. This is what you will need to pay for. However, this should not cost very much... any hosting/email provider should give you this facility. A one off fee ($10-$40 dollars perhaps) for as many user mailboxes as you require, but limited by overall storage.

(*Gmail for business* charge $50 per user/mailbox - but provide a lot more than you seem to require.)

Comment: `A one off fee ($10-$40 dollars perhaps) for as many user mailboxes as you require.` -> Can you give me examples of services? SMTP server as a one off fee. SMTP as a service without an email box? Just aliases?

Comment: It would really be any hosting (or email only) service. These would be mailboxes (email accounts) that will then give you access to an SMTP server. You wouldn't get an SMTP server without the corresponding mailbox I don't think.

Comment: if you already have a domain name, you usually get a few mailboxes with it, and they usually provide an SMTP service. I use Gandi.net, and they allow you to add as many email addresses as you want, but you have to pay $1.30/GB/month up to 50GB of storage (shared by all users).